# Windows Forms WebView2 Runtime Not Found Exception although it is installed

Tags: winforms, .net-4.8, webview2

I am trying to initialize a WebView2 component in a Windows Forms using .Net4.8
getting the below error:

Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.WebView2RuntimeNotFoundException: 'Couldn't find a compatible Webview2 Runtime installation to host WebViews.'

> FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)

It happens on this line:

```
await PowerBi_web.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(await CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "WebView2")));
```

[image: I have the run time installed]

[image: The loader .dll is in the .exe folder of the application]

**What could be the problem ?**

Comment: It might be worth asking on their GitHub repro: https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues

Comment: https://github.com/RickStrahl/MarkdownMonster/issues/730#issuecomment-1240849661

Comment: I installed the Run Time with the same user which runs the code

Comment: I've got the same problem with WPF on a Windows 11 machine which has the runtime as part of the OS. I fixed it by installing the Evergreen bootstrapper from this link: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/#download-section which possibly updates the version?

Comment: As far I can tell, this error indicates that the WebView Runitme is not installed. Install (or fix the install of) the runtime, for example by installing the Evergreen Runtime from MS.